# Motor Voltage and Current Limit of Brushed DC Motor

Tags: power, motor, heat

What fundamentally limits the applicable voltage in a motor? From what I understand, the input to the motor is a relatively constant impedance (since speed is on the order of 100 Hz) and it is primarily just the winding resistance.

Then, if I increase the voltage, the current increases, and so does the magnetic force that moves the actual windings. If I put in more and more current through the motor, the drivable mechanical load theoretically can go higher unbounded, but in reality, the temperature will get too high. Does the temperature getting too high increase the winding resistance and limit current? If I could theoretically remove all generated heat, could even the smallest motor drive huge loads because I wouldn't really have any current limit (assuming mechanical components don't break)?

Comment: This is a big subject, and a lot depends on what type of motor you are talking about.  An induction machine will behave differently from a DC machine.  Different designs may have different limitations.  Thermal limits, magnetic saturation, winding insulation, shaft and bearing loads, and winding impedances can all be limiting factors, and the limiting factors may be different for different operating conditions.

Comment: You forgot about coil resistance

Comment: Your title states you are asking about voltage and current limits, but you don't mention current limits in your question.  Can you rephrase?  And, as pointed out, you don't mention what type of motor -- I suspect you're talking about a brushed, permanent-magnet DC motor, but I cannot know that.

Comment: I'm asking about what dictates current limit in a motor (brushed DC motor, I'll clarify that). I think it has to do with the afore-described thermal issue, but that's what I'm wondering.

Comment: @MichaelE  Do you understand how an RL filter limits current?  All inductors and motors have a DCR spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DC Motors are never constant impedance.**
Motor voltage is limited by Core flux near saturation or brush arc temperatures from stored 1/2LI^2 energy dumped into air contacts at extremes but normally limited by Heat rise of motor, if well-designed.  ( that's the arc flame following the rotor commutator especially when slowed down quickly at max RPM)

V/I(f)=Z(f) spans about 100:1 range **from start** to no-load RPM at some applied voltage  and 10:1 at Start:full load

This can vary typically from 8:1 to 12:1 for more efficient motors or 10:1 +/-20%.

The current drops with rising frequency like a series RL filter except for voltage across the inductor drops with rising RPM.

- **Motor Torque is proportional to Current** which starts as V+/DCR=Isurge or also called locked rotor current. Then the current declines as RPM or f increases since the coil inductance X(f)=2pi*fL and the motor also generates a Back EMF to reduce the apparent voltage the coil sees.

Heat Energy uses thermal resistance and is stored like capacitance with mass with some rise time constant.

\$T_{rise}[°C] =_{units}[W]\cdot[°C/W] = Pd*R_{thermal} = I^2DCR * (R_{θjc} + R_{θca})\$ for thermal resistance from wire **j**unctions to **c**ase, R**jc** then in series with **c**ase to **a**mbient, R**ca** .

- With this one can estimate the hot spot and maximum current allowed in a motor at steady state. Motors require locked rotors to be fire-proof protected.

> Car starter motors use Copper brushes for very low contact R and rely on a battery of very low ESR, to draw up to the maximum CCA or cold Cranking Amp rating ( if new),  rated at 7.5V from a 12.5V charged battery.

- Thus total loop motor resistance for 500 A CCA is 5 V / 500 A = 10 mΩ.  The starter DCR must be lower than this.
- Due to the thermal resistance and motor DCR start motors must never be used longer than 30 seconds every minute or 2.
  For a DC motor the torque can be defined as

\$T=kV^2/Z(ω)\$ for \$Z=DCR+ωL\$  and \$RPM=60*2π ω\$

- for motor DC resistance DCR and for **k** which depends on number of poles, phase of rotor.

Power = Torque * RPM * k
with k for units conversion.

Below shows the current response for a RL series circuit which is the same as the no load current ( vertical from left at DC  to right with RPM (f) for some applied constant voltage.
[image]

Here you see a simple L/R=T filter frequency response to current which drops 20 dB or to 10% of the DC current. We often use this ratio for motor surge/starting current = 10:1 (+/-2) of rated current at full load.

160 Hz is equivalent to 9600 RPM where a motor no load RPM is proportional V for a given kV/RPM constant.

You can compute Power loss \$P_D=I^2DCR\$ from the DC coil resistance and current if you know the thermal resistance 'C/W you can then determine the temperature rise and from the mass then the slew rate of temperature rise. This gets complicated with forced-air cooling.

> But at full RPM,  you have to add mechanical R shunted to L which is down to 10x series DCR to compute Pd.
>   When the motor is operating at full load, there will be an electrically equivalent mechanical load R across the coil about 10x DCR.

Here we are ignoring all other sources of losses like , eddy current and commutator losses or even over-voltage core saturation, if you drive it too high in voltage with no load, then L reduces.

## Final take away

- Power at 0 RPM start= 10x rated motor power +/-20% for DC motors
- No-Load Power at max RPM <= 10% Rated Power <= 1% of Start surge power.

If you can understand a simple RL filter then you can learn how a motor works, but these are just a some of the concepts common to DC motors.

Comment: Thanks for all the useful information here! So when I look at a datasheet for a brushed DC motor and I see a "rated load current" for a motor, is this dictated by the thermal capacitive characteristics/steady state temperature of the wires? If I could cool the motor down effectively enough,  this rated load current (and thus output torque) would increase, assuming the motor inductor doesn't saturate?

Comment: No. DC Torque is always inverse to RPM (f) so at max speed there is no torque left , until loaded then RPM drops. then Vbat was =Vbemf but Vemf drops so  Torque rises as (Vdc-Vbemf) /Z  = I and this is due to mechanical load but motor is  Z= (DCR+ ωL//Rload) Always expect Is, start current = 10x unless DCR is given because Is= V/DCR at start. and is 8x~12x I max rated,.

Answer (score 3):

For most types of electric motors, the speed is proportional to voltage or voltage and frequency. The maximum voltage and frequency is limited by the winding insulation, brush/commutator arcing, mechanical speed limitations and magnetic properties.

The impedance is not constant and is not primarily the winding resistance. With no load applied, the effective impedance is high and the motor runs at the highest possible speed for the applied voltage and frequency. The current drawn is low. The electrical power is all being dissipated in resistance, mechanical friction and other losses. When load torque is applied, the speed starts to decrease and the effective impedance decreases allowing current to flow and electrical power to be converted to mechanical power delivered as driving torque and speed.

The maximum driving torque is limited by the area of the air gap and the strength of the magnetic field between the rotating and stationary parts of the motor. The magnetic circuit has a limit to the magnetic field that can flow. In addition, there is a thermal limit to the current that can flow.

The above is a very general and simplified summary. This forum is not suitable for describing all of the details for even one of the many types of electric motors. You need to study text books, course notes or other detailed explanations that can be found online.

Answer (score 1):

Well first off, you don't "put" current into a motor. A motor DRAWS current based on its electrical properties and loading. You make current AVAILABLE to a motor by virtue of connecting it to a voltage potential. When that happens, the motor draws current in order to establish magnetic fields, then once established the magnetic fields interact to create electo-motive force (EMF). From this point on any further discussion diverges based upon what type of electric motor you want to discuss. You mentioned Hz so we can assume you mean an AC motor, but still there are many different varieties that will work and act differently.

But to your point though; *"If I could theoretically remove all generated heat, could even the smallest motor drive huge loads (assuming mechanical components don't break)?"*
You cannot violate the laws of physics. A given mass requires a calculable amount of torque to move it. Torque is what the motor creates with EMF. The more torque you need from a motor, the more mass it requires to create it because generally, the EMF is a function of the electric current passing through conductors to create the magnetic fields and the stronger the field, the more conductors you need, so the larger the motor gets.

But torque can be manipulated via gear / pulley reduction in that you can easily exchange RPMs for torque so, THEORETICALLY, yes a very small motor could "drive" a very large load under the right circumstances. But "drive" needs definition. For example I can use a tiny tiny motor spinning very very fast connected to a tiny gear that is connected to a series of progressively larger and larger gears until I get to a gigantic gear on the huge load and it can turn. But to get the required torque at that final huge load shaft, the final result of the required torque multiplication will result in the huge load turning very very slowly.